# Display HTML page inside mail body with Email-ext plugin

Tags: email, jenkins, email-ext

I'm facing a little problem using Email-ext plugin on Jenkins.

I added the following line to inject my surefire html result to the email sent by the plugin :

```
${FILE,path="server/target/site/surefire-report.html"}
```

and I put contenant type as HTML (text/html)

I'm using Jenkins 1.651.1 and Email-ext plugin 2.42

I receive an e-mail in the end of my build with the following contenent

```
 ${FILE,path="server/target/site/surefire-report.html"}
```

It's like the plugin did not understand any thing.

Do you have an idea ?

any update on that ?
my project structure is like this :

workspace

```
    master
    commun 
    server/target/surefire-report/surefire-report.html
```

Answer (score 1):

#### If you use a custom path this answer is for you

I had a complication trying to achieve this result because my path was dynamically changing and I had to use a variable inside a `FILE` variable. So when I tried any of the following

```
body: '${FILE,path=${report}}'
body: "${FILE,path=${report}}"
body: '''${FILE,path=${report}}'''
```

and many more, it didn't work. On the other hand I couldn't read the file with groovy because of Jenkins restrictions

**My workaround** was to read the html directly with groovy `sh` command like so

```
html_body = sh(script: "cat ${report}", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

and then just send the email

```
emailext replyTo: '$DEFAULT_REPLYTO',
  subject: "subject",
  to: EMAIL,
  mimeType: 'text/html',
  body: html_body
```

where `${report}` was a path to html file like `/var/jenkins/workspace_318/report.html`

Answer (score 0):

Please note that file path is relative to the workspace , if file resides in the root of your workspace , filename alone in the path will work , if it resides in a different location try somthing like this below :

```
${FILE,path="target/surefire-reports/emailable-report.html"}
```

Comment: Yes sure,but my workspace contain many module ( I have a multimodule project), so my mvn surefire-report:report is executed in workspace, and the file generated is under "server/target/site/". This is the relative path to the workspace

Comment: any update on that ?
my project structure is like this :
workspace 
        master
        server/target/surefire-report/surefire-report.html

Comment: try providing the complete path , i.e , give the workspace and file path. you can get the workspace path from the console output, copy the path and append the above path and try , that might work

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. But did not works. I tried all possibilities but nothings. I'm tring to do it by a groov script right now

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the prob where the mail had the command with error coould not find file. Like mentioned above, the html file should be present exactly under the jenkins workspace folder. if not then give the relative path, even an extra "/" in front seems to throw error.
ex:
My file is in C:\CICDJenkins\ReadyAPIReport\summary.html
My jenkins workpace (im using custom workspace) is C:\CICDJenkins

what worked for me is:
${FILE, path="ReadyAPI_report/overview-summary.html"}